# How do you get field properties

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I'm working on a Sencha app and having trouble accessing the fields of a basic model that I've defined.  I use `Ext.define` to define a model and `Ext.create` to create an instance of it.  According to the docs I should be able to access its fields by calling `get.(<fieldname>)` on the field, but it's not working and it's returning null.  Here's the basic code, along with a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gusennan/Vs48R/).

```
Ext.define('App.model.Patient', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    config: {
        fields: ['admissionGuid',
            'firstName', 'middleInitial', 'lastName', 'visitType',
            { name: "visitDate", type: 'date'}]
    }
});​


var newVisit = Ext.create('App.model.Patient', {
        admissionGuid: 1234,
        firstName: "FirstName",
        middleName: "MiddleName",
        lastName: "LastName",
        visitType: "Revisit",
        visitDate: new Date() 
});

alert(newVisit.get('admissionGuid')); // returns null
```

Comment: Your question is confusing. The title said Ext JS, it's tagged with Ext JS/Sencha Touch 2 and written as though it's Sencha Touch 2. The fiddle links Ext JS. Which is it?

Comment: I'm making a Sencha Touch 2 app, but I thought that the class system was shared with ExtJS so linking against ExtJS should be fine for troubleshooting this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is correct using Sencha Touch 2. I've tested it, and it works as expected. Fiddle here using ST: http://www.senchafiddle.com/#6Q9ac

ExtJS and Sencha Touch share similar class systems, but they are not identical.

Answer (score 1):

The data that you passed gets stored in the raw parameter so try this

```
alert(newVisit.raw.admissionGuid);
```

This should work

Comment: You should not need to do this, unless for some reason, you have not defined the specified field in your model.

Answer (score 0):

just an alternative way,

we can also access the data inside model by:

```
*instanceOfModel*.data.*fieldName*
```

so for example with the given code it will be:

```
newVisit.data.admissionGuid
```